# java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException. Cant find the mistake

Tags: java, mysql

i am curently getting this error:

```
java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'FROMusersWHERElogin='Pac1man' ANDpassword='220v'' at line 1
```

What i need to do to fix it?

Here is my query:

```
public void SignUpUser(User user){
        String insert = "INSERT INTO " + Const.USER_TABLE + "(" + Const.USER_NAME + ","
                + Const.USER_SECONDNAME + "," + Const.USER_LOGIN + "," + Const.USER_PASSWORD + ")"
                + "VALUES(?,?,?,?)";
        try {

            PreparedStatement prSt = getDbConnection().prepareStatement(insert);
            prSt.setString(1, user.getName());
            prSt.setString(2, user.getSecondName());
            prSt.setString(3, user.getUserName());
            prSt.setString(4, user.getPasswordName());

            prSt.executeUpdate();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public ResultSet getUser(User user){
        ResultSet resSet = null;

        String select = "SELECT * FROM" + Const.USER_TABLE + "WHERE" +
                Const.USER_LOGIN + "=? AND" + Const.USER_PASSWORD + "=?";

        try {
            PreparedStatement prSt = getDbConnection().prepareStatement(select);
            prSt.setString(1, user.getUserName());
            prSt.setString(2, user.getPasswordName());

            resSet = prSt.executeQuery();
        }   catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }   catch (ClassNotFoundException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return resSet;
}}
```

Any points?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a mistake (missing spaces) in the `select` variable..
Try this:

```
String select = "SELECT * FROM " + Const.USER_TABLE + " WHERE " +
                Const.USER_LOGIN + "=? AND " + Const.USER_PASSWORD + "=?";
```

Comment: I love you :*   Thanks bro

Answer (score 0):

Your query is not valid because you missed to append space.

```
String select = "SELECT * FROM " + Const.USER_TABLE + " WHERE " +
                Const.USER_LOGIN + "=? AND " + Const.USER_PASSWORD + "=?";
```

Using above code now your query string is become

```
 SELECT * FROM users WHERE login='Pac1man' AND password='220v'
```